# Concept of Temporary table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which uses a large employee table (EMP_medicalplan)

Data structure for EMP_medicalplan
(emp id, SSN,medicalPlan_id,startdate,enddate,companyid,etc)
)

Next we have a staging table for monthly report
stgreport table structure
(empid,month,medicalplan,company,etc)

Now we processing reports using loop on SSN on stgreport table to fill Final Report table. For validating some fields currently we are hitting EMP_medicalplantable for every SSN multiple times like below

1. cursor on staging report table for each SSN
2. process count in EMP_medicalplan table for specific duration
3. process count in EMP_medicalplan table for specific company ( if multiple company available)
4. insert into final report table

Now i want to use concept of local temporary table as in SQl server where i will get data from EMP_medicalplan for each SSN once loop starts and process without hitting table each time.

Please comment for more clarifications on query. I have provided basic information.

Comment: Try the bulk collect concept

Comment: If you really have to do it **row-by-row** a.k.a. **slow-by-slow** then at least avoid an explicit cursor. Use a cursor for loop. If you could do the processing in bulk, then make use of **BULK COLLECT**. There is no need of any temporary table. Read more about **collections** and **bulk collect** in the documentation.

Comment: NO i want local temporary table for EMP_medicalplan so that i donot have to select every time from large data for particular SSN.

Comment: You could create a Global Temporary Table (GTT), which is a permanent table that only stores data on a session basis. However, are you sure that you can't do all your steps in one fell swoop? Perhaps if you could knock up an example set of statements/code as to your current process, we could help you improve it without the need for a separate GTT or the row-by-row (aka slow-by-slow) processing it seems you're currently doing.

Comment: Oracle's Global Temporary Table is close in useage to SQL Server's local temp table. Difference is GTT is permanent global object to hold local data. Build ahead and then use as needed. Generally though temp tables are not the right solution in Oracle.

Comment: I cannot share the logic. But I tried one thing using table type with bulk collect. Can we select data from table type?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be go for Materialized view which will keep the replicate data from EMP_medicalplantable.
    Try to schedule the MV refresh just before your next step. In this way your main table doesnt get too much impacted and you will not query main table every time.
    And as suggested once these steps are implemented you can go for BULK COLLECT rather tha going for row by row LOOP proceesing.
    Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have filled a table type you can use it in a query with the SQL TABLE() function. A better way however would be to create your own index on it.
Assuming there is only one record for each SSN and both SSN columns are called 'SSN':

```
DECLARE
   TYPE ssn_table_type IS TABLE OF ssn_cursor
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   my_ssn_table   ssn_table_type;

   TYPE ssn_index_type IS TABLE OF BINARY_INTEGER
      INDEX BY VARCHAR2( 20 );
   my_ssn_index   ssn_index_type;

   my_ssn_record  ssn_cursor%ROWTYPE;
   my_rec_index   BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
   OPEN ssn_cursor;

   FETCH ssn_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO my_ssn_table;

   CLOSE ssn_cursor;

   FOR idx IN my_ssn_table.FIRST .. my_ssn_table.LAST
   LOOP
      my_ssn_index( my_ssn_table( idx ).ssn )  := idx;
   END LOOP;

   FOR rec_todo IN c_todo
   LOOP
      my_rec_index   := my_ssn_index( rec_todo.ssn );
      my_ssn_record  := my_ssn_table( my_rec_index );
   -- Do something useful....
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

By the way, have you looked into the possibility of realising point 2 and 3 by using analytic functions while filling the staging table? The more you can retrieve while filling the staging table, the better. Something like:

```
count(1) over ( partition by company_id ) AS company_count
```